# Sum the values of an array by pairs until finally getting the sum of all the values

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

So I need to sum the elements by pairs, If the array has 12 values inside ([1],[2],[3]...[12]), it has to show then 6 results and then sum again by pairs to finally show the result of the whole array.

As it appears it has to be recursive and sum every value on the array by pairs.

I don't have any idea on how to implement it, help, pls.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int sum(int array[], int size);

int main()
{
    cout << "Size of Array: "; int size; cin >> size;
    int *array = new int[size], Max = 100;

    srand(time(NULL));
    //Inputing array.
    cout << "Enter elements of array followed by spaces: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int)(rand() % Max);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << "\t";
    }

    cout << "Sum of elements of array: " << sum(array, size) << endl;

    return 0;
}

//Function.
int sum(int array[], int counter)
{
    if (counter == 1)
        return array[0];
    else
    {
        return array[0] + sum(array + 1, counter - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is recursion a requirement or is a iterative solution also allowed? Does your method need to have this signature?

Comment: Recursion it's a requirment, but it doesn't matter the signature.

Comment: But if you have an iterative solution I'll welcome it, at this point I'm almost getting stressed.

Comment: Do you know what recursion is?

Comment: Wnat exactly do you mean by "sum by pairs". Can you show an example for the 12 value array.

Comment: Walter, for your type of comment I'm guessing not.


Rishikesh Raje

Yeah! Ok So let's assume we have a smaller array of 8 values, so the values are [2] [5] [6] [7] [1] [9] [4] [9]
So I have to sum the values by pairs, so the array will be now 4 values as [2+5] [6+7] [1+9] [4+9] and so son until I get the answer.

Comment: @MarcoDiezBarrosoZamudio What is the rule if the element count is odd?

Comment: Then I can add a 0 to sum for the last number so it stays as a pair.

Comment: Your code seems to [work ok](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aC2qBRGKXE5890d6), so what is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, this is **homework**, so I'm not giving a solution here, only a hint for how to get there.

The recursion here is to sum up adjacent pairs of array elements, resulting in a *new array* half the size of the original one. The procedure is repeated until the size is one and the total sum is obtained.

This can be implemented by working in place, i.e. w/o more than one array. The signature of the working horse function may look like this:

```
int                   // return: size of array on output
sum_pairs(int*array,  // in/out: array, on output sum of pairs
          int size)   // input:  size of array on input
{
  if(size<=1) return size;
  int out_size = (size+1)/2;
  // your code here
  return out_size;
}
```

Then the final job is trivial

```
int sum_of_array(int*array, int size)
{
  size = sum_pairs(array,size);
  return size<=1? array[0] : sum_of_array(array,size);  // recursive call
}
```

it's actually easier to do this w/o recursion:

```
int sum_of_array(int*array, int size)
{
  while(1 < size=sum_pairs(array,size)) ;
  return array[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! yeah it is, I'm so worn out for 2 weeks of projects and almost no sleep. But I´ll try to implement it! Thanks a lot.